# convert groupby hierarchy into dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

df.groupby(['col1','col2']).count()
My groupby returns a dataframe (shape = 5, 1) like this

```
col1 col2 count
1      1    10
       2     5
       3     2
2      1     4
       2     5
```

I would like to covert this into (5, 3) dataframe with col1 col2 being real columns.

```
col1 col2 count
1      1    10
1      2     5
1      3     2
2      1     4
2      2     5
```

I found several questions on this forum and outside. No luck.

Comment: Use `.reset_index()`.

Comment: Just FYI for new programmers. I had done reset_index didn't get results, hence asked this question. But after reading through the comments from other question, I realized, I need to add inplace=True